# ¿Cómo separar secciones colocadas hacia abajo?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo separar secciones entre sí?, deseo separar las secciones que están colocadas hacia abajo, esta es la imágen de como se visualizan:

[image: secciones]

Este es mi código html:

```
<section class="general">
  <section class="contenedor">
      <article class="marca1">
        <section class="marca1_1" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/diesel.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_2" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/zara.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_3" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/ck.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size:100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_4" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/levis.gif)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_5" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/adidas.png)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_6" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/pepe.png)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
        <section class="marca1_7" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/af.png)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
         <section class="marca1_7" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/ae.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>

      </article>

      <!-- Seccion de imagenes central -->
  <section class="centro">
    <section class="Inicial">
    <article class="imagen1">
      <a  class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg"><section class="imagen1_1" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/MixtoJuvenil.jpg"><section class="imagen1_2" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/MixtoJuvenil.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg"><section class="imagen1_3" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>

    </article>

    <article class="imagen2">
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/NiñoVerano.jpg"><section class="imagen2_1" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/NiñoVerano.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg"><section class="imagen2_2" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg"><section class="imagen2_3" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
    </article>

    <article class="imagen3">
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg"><section class="imagen3_1" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/PacaCredencial.jpeg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/MixtoJuvenil.jpg"><section class="imagen3_2" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/MixtoJuvenil.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>
      <a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href="assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg"><section class="imagen3_3" style="background:url(assets/images/pacas/MixtaVerano.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: 92%;"></section></a>

    </article>
    </section>
  </section> <!-- fin centro-->


  <article class="marca2">
    <section class="marca2_1" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/lacoste.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
    <section class="marca2_2" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/tommy.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
    <section class="marca2_3" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/converse.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
    <section class="marca2_4" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/lv.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
    <section class="marca2_5" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/gap.jpeg)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section> 
    <section class="marca2_6" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/under2.png)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>
    <section class="marca2_7" style="background:url(assets/images/marcas/columbia.png)no-repeat left center; background-size: 100%;"></section>

  </article>

</section> <!-- fin contenedor -->

</section> <!-- fin general -->
```

Y este es mi código en css:

```
.general{
    margin-top: -19px;
}
.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_1, .contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_6,
.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_1,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_6,
.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_1,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_6 {
    height: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px #01A9DB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px 10px #01A9DB;
    border-bottom-color:#01A9DB ;
    border-top-color: #01A9DB; 
    border-right-color: #01A9DB;
    border-left-color: #01A9DB;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Deseo que entre cada imagen exista un espacio hacia abajo ya que se encuentran muy pegadas, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
.general{ margin-top: -19px; } .contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_1, .contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen1 .imagen1_6, .contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_1,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen2 .imagen2_6, .contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_1,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_2,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_3,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_4,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_5,.contenedor .centro .imagen3 .imagen3_6{ height: 280px; padding-bottom: 3px !important; width: 95%; margin-left: 8px; -webkit-box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px #01A9DB; -moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px 10px #01A9DB; border-bottom-color:#01A9DB ; border-top-color: #01A9DB; border-right-color: #01A9DB; border-left-color: #01A9DB; border-radius: 8px;margin-top:10%; }
```

Comment: Excelente! Muchísimas gracias! @Gustavo Piris